# Blazor - SortBy parameter for table column component

Tags: c#, lambda, blazor, type-parameter

I'm working with Blazor and want to be able to sort a data grid (table) by a given column through a SortBy parameter that takes a lambda expression. It would look something like this:

```blazor
<DataGrid Items="Orders">
  <GridHeader>
    <GridColumn Label="Order Number" SortBy="@(order => order.OrderNumber)" />
    <GridColumn Label="Order Date" SortBy="@(order => order.Date)" />
    <GridColumn Label="Order Status" SortBy="@(order => order.Status)" />
    <GridColumn Label="Number of Line Items" SortBy="@(order => order.LineItems.Count)" />
  </GridHeader>
  <GridRow Context="order">
    <td>@order.OrderNumber</td>
    <td>@order.OrderDate</td>
    <td>@order.Status</td>
    <td>@order.LineItems.Count</td>
  </GridRow>
</Table>
```

The Grid component should be able to take an `IEnumerable` of any type (like `IEnumerable<Order>`), so the `<DataGrid>` component should have a generic type associated with it's row items, set via `@typeparam TableItem`. What I'm having trouble with is being able to reference that `TableItem` type within the `GridColumn` `SortBy` parameter. I need it so that my code editor (Visual Studio) recognizes the `TableItem` type within the `SortBy` lambda expression, so that (in this example) when I start to type `SortBy="@(order => order.)"` then it recognizes order as type `Order` and intellisense will bring up the properties of that type. I think the solution has something to do with using cascading parameters (`CascadingValue`) and `@typeparam`, but I haven't been able to get it to work, and wonder if perhaps there's a current limitation of Blazor that prevents this from working (for example, see [this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/7268), which is still open).

Is this even possible, and if so, what's the approach I should be using here?

Answer (score 3):

sorry that I don`t give you a direct answer, but you can see this project for sortable and filterable table including lambda expression. I am using it in my project and for now, is working well. Hope you found it useful :).
[Blazor sortable table](https://github.com/IvanJosipovic/BlazorTable).

Answer (score 0):

I dont't fully understand - Do you want to specify how each column is ordered individually or do you want to specify by what property of the entity represented in the grid, all items are to be ordered?
The first would not make sense, since the columns would not have any relationship with one another. The latter makes more sense and actually gets close to how I did it, but I would not call it `SortBy`, I would rather call it `Property` because you can specify what property is being represented in that column with that expression, but let me elaborate...

Generally how you do that heavily depends on how your components are made up. I myself tried to develop a DataGrid component as well and I ended up building on top of [this](https://www.meziantou.net/creating-a-datagrid-component-in-blazor.htm). I have customized it a lot and one of those customizations was sorting. It is actually a lot easier than you'd think.

The way the example from the link works is: You specify a property with the expression on the column. That expression can then be compiled and used to draw out the value of the property expressed from the entity specified (try to dig in the code, it's in the GridColumns `CellTemplate`). The `<th>` and `<td>` elements are being build up with the `RenderTreebuilder`.

Now to implement sorting you can do the following and create a public method `.SortItems(Func<TEntity, object> sortFunc)` on the DataGrid, that accepts a func that specifies a property that is to be sorted after. This can be the expression specifed when setting the property represented by that column. This `SortFunc` can be directly used by `.OrderBy()` and `.OrderByDescending()` being applied on your list of items before passing it along to the markup.

```
// ChildGridColumn
// Method being called when clicking a column header, passes along property func
private void OnSort()
{
    if (CompiledProperty != null)
        ParentDataGrid?.SortItems(CompiledProperty);
}

// ParentGrid
// SortMode differentiating ascending and descending sort modes.
public enum SortMode
{
    Ascending,
    Descending,
}

// Method sets the specfified sortFunc, provided by the GridColumn
public void SortItems(Func<TEntity, object> sortFunc)
{
    SortFunc = sortFunc;

    if (SortMode == SortMode.Ascending)
        SortMode = SortMode.Descending;
    else if (SortMode == SortMode.Descending)
        SortMode = SortMode.Ascending;

    StateHasChanged();
}

// Method sorts according to the SortMode
private IEnumerable<TEntity> GetSortedItems()
{
    return SortMode switch
    {
        SortMode.Descending => Items.OrderByDescending(SortFunc),
        SortMode.Ascending or _ => Items.OrderBy(SortFunc),
    };
}
```

If you wonder how to add and event handler to an HTML element build by the `RenderTreeBuilder`, here another short example:

```
var style = GetHeaderStyle();
var clickEvent = EventCallback.Factory.Create<MouseEventArgs>(this, OnSort);

builder.OpenElement(0, "td");

builder.AddAttribute(1, "width", Width);
builder.AddAttribute(2, "style", style);
builder.AddAttribute(3, "onclick", clickEvent);
builder.AddAttribute(4, "onmouseleave", hoverEvent);
builder.AddContent(5, title);

builder.CloseElement();
```

You should look it up, it's pretty easy to learn and there are plenty of expressive enough resources.